# android sqlite how to order by time

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i order my SQLITE database in descending order, for an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948435/how-do-i-order-my-sqlite-database-in-descending-order-for-an-android-app)

I've the following table where i'd like to select the contents of the table but order by the C_TAG_SCAN_TIME field DESC.

```
public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // special for id internally in system
    public static final String C_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String C_COMPANY_ID = "companyid";
    public static final String C_PERSON_ID = "person";
    public static final String C_NAME = "name";
    public static final String C_TAG_ID = "tagid";
    public static final String C_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String C_TAG_SCAN_TIME = "tagscantime";
    public static final String C_TAG_SENTSERVER_TIME = "tagsentservertime";
    public static final String C_TRANSACTIONS_LATITUDE = "transactionslatitude";
    public static final String C_TRANSACTIONS_LONGITUDE = "transactionslongitude";
```

.

This is my query to select everything from the table TRANSACTIONS.

```
return db.query(DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

My question is how can i change the query to order descendingly on the C_TAG_SCAN_TIME column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this...

```
return db.query(DBHelper.TABLETRANSACTIONS, null, null, null, null, null, C_TAG_SCAN_TIME + " DESC");
```