# Order table by date stored in text column

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sql-order-by

I have and app and storing some data on SQLite. And i have a column named date and storing string data format like:

> 30.12.2018 - some data
>   01.01.2019 - some data
>   31.12.2018 - some data
>   02.01.2019 - some data

but when i want to `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date`, this doesn't work correctly. Can I order this table according to correct date order without changing date format?

E.g. when I use `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date` the desired result:

> 02.01.2019 - some data
>   01.01.2019 - some data
>   31.12.2018 - some data
>   30.12.2018 - some data

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948435/how-do-i-order-my-sqlite-database-in-descending-order-for-an-android-app or are you using Room?

Comment: The probable cause for not ordering right is that since it is a String then the "some data" part is influencing the sorting. You should remove that part from the field (creating a new column possibly) and then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the format of this column in order to avoid situations 
where you need statements like this:

```
select * from mytable 
order by 
substr(date, 7, 4) || substr(date, 4, 2) || substr(date, 1, 2) || substr(date, instr(date, '-')) desc
```

This part:

```
substr(date, 7, 4) || substr(date, 4, 2) || substr(date, 1, 2)
```

rearranges the date to `YYYYMMDD` so it's comparable and can be sorted.