# sqlite sorting by WHERE first

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to sort some data in my android app with sqlite with the query

```
cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, DRILL_TYPE + " IN ('type 1', 'type 2');", null, null, null, SIZE + " ASC", null);
```

I'm expecting the results to come out sorted by size, regardless of whether the drill is type 1 or 2, but I'm getting all of type 1 sorted, and then I'm getting all of type 2 sorted.  What's wrong with my query that's resulting in this?

```
expected:
type 1     1
type 2     2
type 1     3
type 2     4
type 1     5
type 2     6

actual result:
type 1     1
type 1     3
type 1     5
type 2     2
type 2     4
type 2     6
```

## Edit, after the original question was answered :-

removing the semicolon at the end of the order part fixed things when I use IN, but not when I use NOT IN

Comment: I think you can find your answer in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8948476/10915910) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue may be due to the semi-colon **`;`** at the end of the IN clause. This would effectively mark the end of the SQL and as such result in the ORDER clause being ignored/omitted.

That is try :-

```
cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, DRILL_TYPE + " IN ('type 1', 'type 2')", null, null, null, SIZE + " ASC", null);
```

In regard to :-

> removing the semicolon at the end of the order part fixed things when
>   I use IN, but not when I use NOT IN

Using

```
 cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, DRILL_TYPE + " NOT IN ('type 1', 'type 2')", null, null, null, SIZE + " ASC", null);
```

would sort the rows, that do not have **type 1** or **type 2**, correctly, consider the following (which replicates your situation but with extra data to show the NOT IN results):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (drill_type TEXT, size INTEGER);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('type 2',4),('type 1',5),('type 2',6),
    ('type 1',1),('type 2',2),('type 1',3),
    ('type 4',14),('type 3',15),('type 4',16),
    ('type 3',11),('type 4',12),('type 3',13)
;

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE drill_type IN ('type 1','type 2') ORDER BY size ASC;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE drill_type NOT IN ('type 1','type 2') ORDER BY size ASC;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE drill_type NOT IN ('type 1','type 2'); ORDER BY size ASC; -- will not sort as expected
```

- Note the above effectively replicates your code

The results would be :-

1. original solution

[image]

2. using NOT IN correctly

[image]

3. leaving the semi-colon in

[image]

Comment: That worked! It's always a semi-colon's fault.  However, now when I try the statement with NOT IN instead, I get the same problem

Comment: @vugavich Correctly using `....., " NOT IN ('type 1', 'type 2')", .....` would work. Impossible to know what you are doing wrong for it to not work without code itself.