# How to Print Media Files in DESCENDING Order

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver

I am Accessing media files using cursor in a array. But i need to print the array i descending order (Meaning Latest Media File in System First)

```
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, " DESC");
```

I Have Tried this but it does not work and application crashes.

```
public ArrayList < String > getAllMedia() {
    HashSet < String > videoItemHashSet = new HashSet < > ();
    String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, " DESC");
    try {
        Objects.requireNonNull(cursor).moveToFirst();
        do {
            videoItemHashSet.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ArrayList < > (videoItemHashSet);
}
```

Comment: there is no column name in your: `" DESC"`

Comment: If you read your crash log, I expect you'll find something explaining that you need to specify a column along with DESC

Comment: How Do i Specify Column Name...?

Comment: [How do i order my SQLITE database in descending order, for an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948435/how-do-i-order-my-sqlite-database-in-descending-order-for-an-android-app) - I'm aware you're using a ContentResoler and not a SQLite db, but the syntax is the same in this case.

Comment: by writing its name in front of " DESC"

Comment: I Got it...Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only `DESC`, you will have to describe according to which attribute you want to sort data. So instead use this:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
```